# Planteamiento correcto en la lógica de un paginador

Tags: php

Antes de nada desconozco si puedo realizar este tipo de preguntas, en las cuales no se pone código, si no en discutir cual es la lógica a la hora de programar algo.

Quiero hacer un paginador, si ya se que podría buscar miles, per quiero hacerlo yo mismo. Pero tengo dudas en como plantear la lógica del mismo.

Lo que yo he pensado es lo siguiente:

Primero por medio de una consulta a la tabla de la bbdd, averiguar cuales son el número totales de registros en una tabla. Una vez hecho eso dividirlo por ejemplo por 10 para mostrar 10 registros por página, para así saber las páginas totales, y pasarle por la url, dependiendo de esta mostrará una unos resultados y otros.

Por ejemplo **noticias.php?pag=1** mostraría los ultimos 10 registros. **noticias.php?pag=2** mostraria del 11 al 20. Y así con todas las páginas.

Sería este el planteamiento de la lógica correcto ? O hay formas más eficientes de hacerlo ?

Comment: Para que esto parezca más una pregunta, podrías incluir el código PHP de cómo implementarías todo lo que dices ;) (que a mi parecer va bien, pero sigue estando en el aire...)

Comment: Realmente existe varias formas de implementarlo (Uno mejores que otras), sin embargo existe framework de trabajo que te ayuda con el págineo, como por ejemplo: [Data table](https://datatables.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Considera que tienes dos datos importantes: el número de elementos en la db, y el array de datos. Una buena idea (desde mi punto de vista) es NO HACER dos consultas, una misma debe ser capaz de determinar si vas por el count de rows o por el array de datos, esto agregando (o no) a la consulta

> LIMIT 0, 10 (LIMIT tuoffset,valoresXpagina)

cuando es la página 1,

> LIMIT 10,20

cuando es la segunda, etc.

Algo más que veo en tu planteamiento es dividir el total entre 10 para mostrar 10 registros por página... no me lo imagino, pienso que el total/valoresXpagina da el número de páginas.